# meteor support for angularjs, skipping handlebars

Tags: meteor

I am NOT much used to `handlebars`, can i completely skip handlebars and use angular. I see couple of libraries of angular in mtr which one to use, please suggest? Also provide any feedback if there will be problems in my app if i completely go the angular way in meteor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `angular` very well, but I've already tried using meteor with `KnockoutJS`. My first impressions are that this should work fine. However, one important thing to keep in mind is that those frameworks use totally different dependency tracking system and in some cases it can be tricky to synchronize them with `meteor`, e.g. with reactive data sources like `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

Loneleeandroo has a great package on GitHub called ngMeteor to use for integrating the two frameworks together. It's really, really slick. Here's a link for you: https://github.com/loneleeandroo/ngMeteor/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The **angular-meteor** project has the most traction on github, is actively maintained, and has a well done tutorial.
http://angular-meteor.com/

tutorial
http://angular-meteor.com/tutorial

github
https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor